# Failing to boot Ubuntu 18.04 - "attempt to read or write outside of 'hd0'"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, lvm, grub

I am having issues booting and end up in a grub rescue shell.

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Searching around the web, i have found some commands to get a bit more information about my system.
Running `sudo fdisk -l` gives

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1864450048 bytes, 3641504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.7 MiB, 36323328 bytes, 70944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 140.9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2433024 bytes, 4752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.5 MiB, 15196160 bytes, 29680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 3.7 MiB, 3887104 bytes, 7592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x99811f5b

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 488396799 488394752 232.9G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15524167680 bytes, 30320640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x32234161

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     8064 30320639 30312576 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)




Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 231.9 GiB, 249028411392 bytes, 486383616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 980 MiB, 1027604480 bytes, 2007040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

From which we can see my main drive is /dev/sda and the root and swap use lvm.
The /dev/sda and /dev/sda1 have the boot flag. It is pretty much a standard unbuntu installation. The /dev/sdb is the usb drive i am using right now to run my computer.

To me, all seems fine and i am out of idea on how to get my desktop back. How should one approch this problem to solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Dropping a bounty on this. I have this happening on a server with an HP Enterprise SSD in it. It happens very frequently when rebooting. I have the luxury of wiping the install and reprovisioning the disk with ansible afterwards as this is just the root disk, but this keeps reoccurring. It's not a one off problem. And it's 18.04 specific. I would like a way to recover without a wipe.

Comment: Just found this, looks like this issue is a mixed bag: https://askubuntu.com/questions/229715/booting-ubuntu-failure-error-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0

Comment: Have you tried this method shown in askubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error

Comment: I think your question lacks information about your grub install and settings, since it is a grub problem. From https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Device-syntax I find strange Grub would read from "hd0" when LVM is supposed to be named "lvm". It may be easier to have a small physical /boot partition. See also https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to ask: have you tried reinstalling grub?